# pass / share class with SpriteView GameScene from a SwiftUi View

Tags: class, swiftui, spriteview

I am playing around with SpriteView, which works great. However I cannot figure out how to share a class with Spritekit GameScene,that is instantiated in one my views. Sharing my class with other views works like a charm. But how can I access my gameCenterManager class from spritekit's GameScene, how do I pass the class ? I don't have any clue how to do this. I considered making a global accessible class, but its not what I want.

The goal is to be able to send and receive data from inside GameScene to update players location and etc. But the matchmaking happens inside a SwiftUI View, which is also where the class is created.

The gameCenterManger class is created like so;

```
struct ContentView: View {
   
    @StateObject var gameCenterManager = GameCenterManager()
    
    var body: some View {

    ...
    etc
```

the class is set up like so :

```
class GameCenterManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {

   //lots of stuff going on
   ...

}
```

And is shared to the GameSceneView view that will create the SpriteView, like so :

```
    Button("Show Sheet") {
            self.showingSheet.toggle()
    }
    .buttonStyle(RoundedRectangleButtonStyle())
    .buttonStyle(ShadowButtonStyle())
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showingSheet, content: { GameSceneView(gameCenterManager:self.gameCenterManager)})
```

Finally, inside my GameSceneView, the GameScene for SpriteView is configured.

```
struct GameSceneView: View {
    
    var gameCenterManager: GameCenterManager
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width , height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill

        return scene
    }

    var body: some View {
        
        Button("Dismiss") {
            self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()

        }
        
        Button("send data") {
            gameCenterManager.increment()
        }
        

        SpriteView(scene: scene )
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - 200 )
            .ignoresSafeArea()
            .overlay(ImageOverlay(), alignment: .bottomTrailing)
            
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps others are looking to do the same? Here below is the answer in code snippets

GameCenterManager is the class that I want to access across all views and SKScenes

In mainview:

```
   @main    
   struct gameTestApp: App {
        
        @StateObject var gameCenterManager = GameCenterManager()
        
        var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                ContentView().environmentObject(gameCenterManager)
            }
        }
    }
```

In Contentview view add :

```
@EnvironmentObject var gameCenterManager:GameCenterManager
```

And where I transition to GameSceneView inside Contentview, which will load my SKScene

```
    Button("Show Sheet") {
            self.showingSheet.toggle()
    }
    .buttonStyle(RoundedRectangleButtonStyle())
    .buttonStyle(ShadowButtonStyle())
    
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showingSheet, content: { GameSceneView()})
```

Then in GameSceneView add:

```
@EnvironmentObject var gameCenterManager:GameCenterManager
```

and where we load SKScene:

```
var scene: SKScene {
        let scene = GameScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width , height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
        scene.scaleMode = .fill
        scene.gameCenterManager = gameCenterManager

        return scene
    }
```

Then finally in GameScene itself add:

```
var gameCenterManager: GameCenterManager?
```